# How to kill files with cyrillic letters in name?

Tags: vba

I need to delete all the files in the folder.

The code runs when file names consist of latin letters.

When any of the files contain cyrillic letters, it returns

> runtime error 52 (Bad file name or number)

It worked with cyrillic letters on my old PC.

```vb
Sub Kill1()

    Dim aFile As String
    aFile = "C:\Users\belose\Downloads\temp\*.*"
    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
        Kill aFile
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post an example filename in Cyrillic that won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. I have Win 10. I went to the Settings->Time and language->Additional date time settings->Change location and chose Russia. Before I had just a similar issue with python and then I felt that it's not the problem of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Per comment from the OP, the solution was to change the regional settings.

```
Settings->Time and language->Additional date time settings->Change location and chose Russia
```

---

The Dir function does not support Unicode characters. Try using the FileSystemObject instead.

The following example loops through each file in the specified folder, and then deletes any file that contains one of the specified file extensions.

Change the path to the source folder accordingly. Also, add and/or change the file extensions as desired.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteFiles()

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim sourceFolder As Object
    Set sourceFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\users\domenic\desktop") 'change the path accordingly
    
    Dim currentFile As Object
    For Each currentFile In sourceFolder.Files
        Select Case fso.GetExtensionName(currentFile)
            Case "txt", "csv", "xlsx", "xlsm" 'add and/or change the file extensions as desired
                fso.DeleteFile currentFile.Path
        End Select
    Next currentFile
    
    Set currentFile = Nothing
    Set sourceFolder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it works! Just wondering why Kill could work on my previous PC.

Comment: Domenic, I found the root cause. I have Win 10. I went to the Settings->Time and language->Addditional date time settings->Change location and chose Russia. Before I had just a similar issue with python and then i felt that it'snot the problem of the code.